# New documentation for Facebook Realtime Updates (Realtime API) incomplete?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It seems that the new documentation for realtime updates is incomplete:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/subscriptions/

The previous documentation described how to register an app for a specific page using the endpoint "/tabs?app_id=" to receive realtime updates for a page using an app.

The current documentation only describes how to add subscriptions for pages for an app using the Graph API (which was previously done in the app console) but doesn't describe anything else. However adding a subscription is not sufficient, no realtime updates will be delivered unless the app is registered for the page as described above.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I thought, it was missing in the documentation. I filed a documentation bug and it's fixed now:
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/371249006351460/